# Script from cron doesn't create archive

Tags: cron, backup

I'm using:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
```

Have an script in user's crontab:

```
$ crontab -l
0 7 * * * /home/teamcity/scripts/TC_backup.sh
```

If I run this script under this very user - it's create needed archive:

```
$ /home/teamcity/scripts/TC_backup.sh
...
```

And from local-scripts-log:

```
$ cat /var/log/teamcity_backup.log | tail -n 20
Exporting TeamCity data directory: Exporting build logs
Exporting TeamCity data directory: Exporting personal changes
Finalizing export...
Export has completed successfully.
Backup file created: /home/teamcity/backups/TeamCity_20140117_172034.zip
Backup finished
Done.


   Free disc space: 147G;
   Used disc space: 125M.


   Last archives available:

55M Jan 17 17:21 TeamCity_20140117_172034.zip
55M Jan 17 17:14 TeamCity_20140117_171318.zip
16M Dec 17 18:43 TeamCity_20131217_184333.zip

   Backup finished at 2014-01-17--17-21
```

And have files:

```
$ ls -l /home/teamcity/backups/
total 127656
-rw-rw-r-- 1 teamcity teamcity 16777213 Dec 17 18:43 TeamCity_20131217_184333.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 teamcity teamcity 56914703 Jan 17 17:14 TeamCity_20140117_171318.zip
-rw-rw-r-- 1 teamcity teamcity 57022673 Jan 17 17:21 TeamCity_20140117_172034.zip
```

But - I haven't any `*.zip` from other days.

In cron-log I see that script started without errors:

```
Jan 12 07:00:01 lms-teamcity CROND[11878]: (teamcity) CMD (/home/teamcity/scripts/TC_backup.sh)
```

Contents of the script:

```
BDIR="/home/teamcity/backups/"
LOGFILE="/var/log/teamcity_backup.log"
ARHNAME="TeamCity"
backup () {
    /home/teamcity/TeamCity/bin/maintainDB.sh backup --all -M -F $BDIR/$ARHNAME >> $LOGFILE
}
backup
```

What can be the cause?

UPD: 2> errorlog.file doesn't give result:

```
$ crontab -l
0 7 * * * /home/teamcity/scripts/TC_backup.sh 2> /var/log/teamcity_backup_error.log

$ file /var/log/teamcity_backup_error.log
/var/log/teamcity_backup_error.log: empty
```

In cron-log also no any errors:

```
...
Jan 20 09:00:01 lms-teamcity CROND[24816]: (setevoy) CMD (/home/setevoy/scripts    /db_con_test-4.sh)
Jan 20 09:00:01 lms-teamcity CROND[24818]: (teamcity) CMD (/home/teamcity/scripts/TC_backup.sh 2> /var/log/teamcity_backup_error.log)
Jan 20 09:00:01 lms-teamcity CROND[24817]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
...
```

Comment: Capture the error output of your cron to see what's going on: `0 7 * * * /home/teamcity/scripts/TC_backup.sh 2> /tmp/back.log`.

Comment: 90% of the time these issues are caused because cron runs with a very minimal environment.  You don't get the same environment as an interactive user session (under which you're manually running the script).  So, make sure your script has the right environment setup.

Comment: @EightBitTony

Donn't sure quite understood you... Script very simple and it's just run other one from itself:

    `BDIR="/home/teamcity/backups/"
    LOGFILE="/var/log/teamcity_backup.log"
    ARHNAME="TeamCity"

    backup () {
    /home/teamcity/TeamCity/bin/maintainDB.sh backup --all -M -F $BDIR/$ARHNAME >> $LOGFILE
    }

    backup;`

Neither `TC_backup.sh` or `maintainDB.sh` doesn't use any user/system variables...

Comment: If it works when run from the command line, and not from cron, 90% of the time it *is* a problem with the user environment, because that is the key difference between running under an interactive shell and running under cron.  You can diagnose this stuff by including more logging, checking stderr, and also running `env` at the start of the script and capturing the output.  Even the `$PATH` is likely to be different.

Comment: Thanks, @EightBitTony - I added 2> output as **terdon** suggested - hope will have additional info. And added `env >> file` in to backup script beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сause was in `JAVA_HOME` variable, as it needed by `maintainDB.sh` script.

So, getting info from script running from cron:

```
getenv () {
env >> $BDIR/envlog.log
}
...
getenv;
...
```

And than checking file to variable:

```
$ cat envlog.log | grep JAVA
```

Show nothing.

After adding:

```
...
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/"
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=768m"
export JRE_HOME="/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_45/jre"
...
```

In to this very backup script `TC_backup.sh` - all work good.

Answer (score 2):

You're most likely getting an error that you can't see because you aren't capturing `STDERR` anywhere. You're only capturing `STDOUT`. Usually cron will e-mail the user with any output (whether `STDOUT` or `STDERR`). Who is receiving mail for the teamcity user on this host?

In `TC_backup.sh` capture `STDERR`:

```
/home/teamcity/TeamCity/bin/maintainDB.sh backup --all -M -F $BDIR/$ARHNAME >>$LOGFILE 2>>$ERRORLOG
```

Then check your error log.